# xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token) due to "<" symbol in script

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse web page to save some data from it in excel or csv file.

```
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = "http://rusdrama.com/afisha"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
content = response.read()
root = ET.fromstring(content)
```

When parsing page using fromstring method ElementTree I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PythonProjects/PythonMisc/theater_reader.py", line 7, in <module>
    root = ET.fromstring(content)
  File "D:\Python\Python35\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1333, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 49, column 14
```

The part of received page is the following:

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 100) {
            jQuery(".t3-header").addClass("solid");
        }
        if (scroll <= 100) {
            jQuery(".t3-header").removeClass("solid");
        }
    });
    })
</script>
```

And specifically line 49:

```
    if (scroll <= 100) {
```

So the problem is in opening angle bracket that seems to be processed as opening tag symbol.
I saw several similar questions but can't understand how to handle this situation.

Comment: you are opening this with an XML parser. XML requires `<`, `>` and `&` to be escaped.

Comment: you may want to use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think to use not xml parser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You are trying to parse HTML with an XML parser.* Use a proper tool, an HTML Parser, instead: [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) are the most popular.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib.request
>>> 
>>> url = "http://rusdrama.com/afisha"
>>> response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
>>>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
>>> print(soup.title.get_text())
Афиша Харьковского академического русского драматического театра Пушкина
```